# In popup document.getElementById(tur).value it is coming in IE but isnt coming in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

My problem is with popup. I use `document.getElementById(tur).value` in popup but it is workin in IE but isnt working Chrome. i wrote alert but didnt anything.

```
function birimSec(tur,id,txt)
{   
        alert(document.getElementById(tur).value);//doesnt work
        document.getElementById(tur).value=id;
        document.getElementById(tur+'ACK').value=txt;

        if(document.getElementById(tur).onchange != null)
            document.getElementById(tur).onchange();


}
```

'tur' is coming correct and it is working in IE but in Chrome doesnt working wh ?
thans for everything.

Comment: Does the pop-up even appear in Chrome? Chrome does block pop-ups by default if I am not wrong.

Comment: Which IE version did you test in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used this code and it is working now :)

```
var win = ifrm.contentWindow; // reference to iframe 2 window
// reference to iframe 2 document
var doc = ifrm.contentDocument? ifrm.contentDocument: ifrm.contentWindow.document;
// reference to form element in iframe 2 document
var fld = doc.forms['formName'].elements[tur];
var counter = win.counter; // global variable in iframe 2
win.clearGreeting(); // call function in iframe 2
```

the iframe in parent page. thanks everybody

Answer (score 0):

What code is used to call this? The problem is more likely to be there than in the function itself.

Comment: it is calling this function : function listele(id,txt) 
{
 window.opener.birimSec('<%=tur%>',id,txt);
 
}

Comment: Sorry miss read you comment. Could it be that the DOM element hasn't loaded correctly yet?

Comment: yes it is correctly i tested and it is working in IE

Comment: and tur is comming 'birim' but alert(document.getElementById(tur)) is comming null please help me

Comment: the code might fire earlier in the process in Chrome that IE. Is this a modal pop up and the document.getElementById(tur) is selecting an element in that popup?

Comment: no it is jsp page only not modal popup. And only selection field and another fields are coming to combobox in parent page